# "timeout: timed out" when creating database using PyOrient

Tags: orientdb, pyorient, database-create

I've had a local instance of OrientDB (version:2.2.20) which i'm using it as graph database. When i tried to create new database from DB Client instance it gives time out error. The code is shown below,

```
import pyorient

####establishing connection with OrientDB

client=pyorient.OrientDB('localhost',2424)
session_id=client.connect('root','kavin')

####connect to database
####create one when there is no database
if client.db_exists('sample_db',pyorient.STORAGE_TYPE_MEMORY):
    client.db_open('sample_db','root','kavin')
    print('db exists')

else:
    print('db doesn\'t exists')
    client.db_create('sample_db',pyorient.DB_TYPE_GRAPH,pyorient.\
                                                STORAGE_TYPE_MEMORY

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
.......
timeout: timed out
```

The client object gives me other existing database and the connection doesnt have any problems. Please suggest me to deal with it

Comment: which version of python and pyorient are you using?

Comment: Python Version 2.7.12 and of PyOrient is 1.5.5

Comment: uhm, I copy/pasted your exact code and is working for me

Comment: Whether it has anything to do with version?

Comment: don't think so, I'm using python 2.7.11 and pyorient 1.5.5

Comment: Is the db active and running, is it accessible on the port indicated in the code? Can you post the whole error and/or full server logs.

Comment: I can able to access other databases and query it...The whole error message is...Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
       client.db_create('sample_db')....time out : timed out...is the error i'm getting...

Comment: I have the same issue in pyorient 1.5.5 with python 3.5.2. server log says  "INFO  {db=db_name} Created database 'db_name' of type 'plocal'". But in debugger the execution is stuck at db_create..